# Elasticsearch completion suggester query in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I was not able to find a working example on how to query Elasticsearch using the completion suggester in PHP (elasticsearch-php).

Querying via CURL, e.g.

```
curl -X POST 'localhost:9200/tstidx/_suggest?pretty' -d '{
"try" : {
    "text" : "a",
    "completion" : {
        "field" : "suggest"
    }
}
}'
```

works, so the only problem is the query part in PHP.

How do I use the API to query Elasticsearch using the completion suggester?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP ES client has a method called [`suggest`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php/blob/37a572b99b443f907cd3b0a2801fcdea3cbd9d31/docs/build/Elasticsearch/Client.asciidoc#Elasticsearch_Clientsuggest_suggest) that you can use for that purpose:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'tstidx',
    'body' => [
        'try' => [
            'text' => 'a',
            'completion' => [ 'field' => 'suggest' ]
        ]
    ]
];

$client = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$response = $client->suggest($params);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to highlight the matching parts?

Comment: Good thing you have [asked a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38070952/how-to-hightlight-matches-in-elasticsearch-completion-suggester) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the PHP elasticsearch API

```
    <?Php 
       include 'autoload.php';
       $elastic_search = new ElasticApiService();
       $search_params = array(
           'index' => 'my_index',
           'search_type' =>  'match',
           'search_key' => 'citynamefield',
           'search_value' => 'orlando'
       );
       $search_results = $elastic_search->searchElastic($search_params);
       echo '<pre>';
print_r($search_results);
```

Comment: You can also use wild cards in version 7.6.1 of the engine

Comment: {
      "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "query" : "Orl*",
            "default_field" : "poname"
        }
      }
    }