# How to hightlight matches in Elasticsearch completion suggester

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to highlight the matching parts in the results of a completion suggester query?

Answer (score 3):

(Caveat: I am new to Elasticsearch and the answer given relies solely on the two links I posted below. However, these are official Elasticsearch / Lucene sources and they are pretty clear about it)

As of today (2016-06-28), it does not seem to be possible.

This feature would not be implemented in Elasticsearch but in the underlying Lucene. However, it seems to be a complex issue that is not going to be resolved anytime soon.

See:

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8089

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4518