# Illegal Argument Exception when using Suggestors in Elasticsearch in PHP

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have tried implementing completion suggestor query in php as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064046/elasticsearch-completion-suggester-query-in-php). My code is :

```
$params = [
            "index" => $myIndex,
            "body" => [
                "try" => [
                    "text" => "ram",
                    "completion" => [ "value" => "suggest"]
                ]
            ]
        ];

        $response = $client->suggest($params);
```

I have done indexing like this:

```
$params = [
        "index" => $myIndex,
            "body" => [
            "settings"=> [
            "analysis"=> [
                "analyzer"=> [
                "start_with_analyzer"=> [
                    "tokenizer"=> "my_edge_ngram",
                    "filter"=> [
                    "lowercase"
                    ]
                ]
                ],
                "tokenizer"=> [
                "my_edge_ngram"=> [
                    "type"=> "edge_ngram",
                    "min_gram"=> 3,
                    "max_gram"=> 15
                ]
                ]
            ]
            ],
            "mappings"=> [
            "doc"=> [
                "properties"=> [
                "label"=> [
                    "type"=> "text",
                    "fields"=> [
                    "keyword"=> [
                        "type"=> "keyword"
                    ],
                    "ngramed"=> [
                        "type"=> "text",
                        "analyzer"=> "start_with_analyzer"
                    ]
                    ]
                ]
                ]
            ]
            ]
    ]
    ];
    $response = $client->indices()->create($params);    // create an index
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "[completion] unknown field [value], parser not found"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "[completion] unknown field [value], parser not found"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I have tried changing `value` to `value.keyword` but it is showing same error. I am using elastic search 5.3.2 . How to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you please share your Elasic Search mapping here, it would be helpful to understand the problem better.

Comment: @AmanGarg I have added that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the query you are using field 'value' inside the completion while it is not a field like this, that is the exact error is stating.

You can try the below solution:

```
    $params = [
                "index" => $myIndex,
                "body" => [
                    "try" => [
                        "text" => "ram",
                        "completion" => [ "label" => "suggest"]
                    ]
                ]
            ];
   $response = $client->suggest($params);
```

Hope this will work.